# Style customizing using jQuery (select only odd h3s)

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the odd sub-titles using jQuery!

I have this code right now:

```
  <script>
  $(function() {

    $( ".accordion" ).accordion({
      active: false,
      collapsible: true,
      heightStyle: "content", 
      alwaysOpen: false
    });

    $(".accordion .accordion h3:odd").css( "background-color", "white" );

  });
  </script>


  <p class="question" style="font-size: 19px!important;">
    Contact Us: 
  </p>

  <p class="answer">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  </p>


  <p class="question"  style="font-size: 19px!important;">
    Frequently Asked Questions:
  </p>



<div class="accordion">


  <h3>My Account</h3>

  <div class="accordion">

    <h3 class="rotation">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>
    </div>

    <h3 class="rotation">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>
    </div>

    <h3 class="rotation">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>
    </div>

    <h3 class="rotation">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>
    </div>

    <h3 class="rotation">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>
    </div>

    <h3 class="rotation">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>
    </div>


  </div>

<div class="accordion">


  <h3>My Account</h3>

  <div class="accordion">

    <h3 class="rotation">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>
    </div>

    <h3 class="rotation">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>
    </div>

    <h3 class="rotation">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>
    </div>

    <h3 class="rotation">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>
    </div>

    <h3 class="rotation">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>
    </div>

    <h3 class="rotation">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </p>
    </div>


  </div>
```

The result isn't 100% ok.

When I have something like this that ends with a gray line: 
[image]

on the next one I get the sub titles starting with a white bg instead of a gray one:

[image]

I didn't succeed doing it using CSS 
If you inssist helping me with the CSS, be my guest :)

http://jsfiddle.net/09c2q7xo/4/
* cant add   `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: can do this with css, no need for jQuery...inspect the live html and rules that apply then adjust accordingly

Comment: I am editing my CSS code to the main post. 
I tried but without any success.

Comment: We can't see your css and can't troubleshoot an image. Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: I added a jsfiddle but the ui isnt working there `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: there's nothing but css there...no html or script. That is not a demo that replicates your problem

Comment: Please refresh the page i updated the link

Comment: resources can be added in resources panel ... if you want help it's incumbent on you to prep demo so it is doing what you see

Comment: I already tried, Not working :S
any idea how to make it work properly?

Comment: @charlietfl I did it! 
you can view the jsfiddle :D !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your jQuery with a simple CSS selector:

```
.accordion .accordion h3:nth-of-type(2n) {
    background-color: white;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/09c2q7xo/5/).

Note: This required CSS3 support level.